# Nodejs distance calculation between hundreds of coordinates is blocking my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, geolocation

I have a list of hundreds of coordinates (lat,lon).
For each client request I need to calculate the distance between each pair of these points.
For a list of 1,000 coordinates - it takes me 500ms to do that, so it is blocking my nodejs server .
How can I 'fix' this by making it async? I don't want it to block my server so it can continue handling other requests ..

Is it recommended to open another nodejs process and make it a 'distance calculation service' or something like that?

Here is a sample test code:

```
var pts=[];
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    pts.push(randomLatLon());
}
var a;
var b;
var i,j;
var start = new Date();
for (i=0;i<pts.length;i++){
    for (j=0;j<pts.length;j++){
        if (i===j) {
            continue;
        }
        a = pts[i];
        b = pts[j];
        var dist = utils.getDistance(a.lat,a.lon,b.lat,b.lon);
    }
}
console.log('total time',new Date()-start,'ms'); // ~500 ms
```

and here is utils.getDistance function:

```
E.getDistance = function(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371*1000; // Radius of the earth in m
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in m
  return d;
}
```

Comment: You should look at process.nextTick() function. I'm not sure it can solve your problem but it is the first track i'll try.

Comment: it will still block the server for 500ms, either way .. it will just delay the blocking to the next tick ..  isn't having an extra, specialized, nodejs server for this task a better option?

Comment: It will not if you refactor your code to do process.nextTick every 100 or 500 distance processed.

Comment: nice approach. so i assume that after every 100 distances processed, node's process.nextTick will make node available for other requests, and thus will be blocked only for the small time that it takes to calc 100 distances.. i'll try that. but still -wouldn't it be simpler (and faster) to make this calc distance in a seperate small nodejs local webserver ? there are no shared resources between the two nodejs process so i on't see any problems with it

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little on what you need to do with the results. Do you need an array of distances as the output?

One approach would be to use promises such as Q to make each calculation into a separate operation and then use `Q.all` to wait for completion of all calculations, but doing that for a 1000x1000 might not be a very good idea though as you would have to keep an array of half a million promises in memory. Depending on what you need to do with the output and how large the original array of points is, it may or may not be better to call each calculation in sequence. One way to do that would be to use recursion:

```
function calculateDistances(pts) {
    var start = new Date();
    calculateNextDistance(pts, 0, 1).then(function() {
        console.log('total time',new Date()-start,'ms');
    });

    function calculateNextDistance(pts, i, j) {
        return Q().then(function () {
            var a = pts[i];
            var b = pts[j];
            var dist = utils.getDistance(a.lat, a.lon, b.lat, b.lon);

            j++;

            if (j == pts.length) {
                i++;
                j = i + 1;
            }

            if (j < pts.length) {
                return calculateNextDistance(pts, i, j);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This seems to work well for me, however note that it may of course take substantially longer time than 500 ms to complete the calculations now, due to all the context switching. One compromise could perhaps be to do a few calculations in each iteration.

(BTW, you could eliminate quite a few calculations by not calculating x->y AND y->x, meaning the loop could go `for (j=i+1;j<pts.length;j++)`, which I also used in my code above)

Whether or not it's better to instead spawn a child process I don't know, it might be worth trying out.